# bibentry does not work with apacite

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, bibentry

Have you managed to use `bibentry` with `apacite`? `bibentry` should work with `apacite` according to the manual of `apacite`, though I can not make it work. And I can not find `bibentry` manual on CTAN. I have found only [this file](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf). `bibentry` is a part of `natbib`, but there is nothing mentioned about `bibentry` in the manual of `natbib`.

`bibentry` works with `natbib` nicely, but I would prefer to use `apacite` rather `natbib`, because `apacite` makes better formatting of bibliography according to the APA style.

I am adding example at the end of the question. The error I am getting is:

```
! Paragraph ended before \citeauthoryear was complete.
```

P.S. I would like to use `biblatex` with `fulecite` command, but unfortunately `biblatex` does not support `polyglossia` which I have to use instead of `babel`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@BOOK{Cochran1977,
  author = {William Gemmell Cochran},
  title = {Sampling Techniques},
  year = {1977},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  address = {New-York},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

% \usepackage{natbib}
% \bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

This is full citation of \bibentry{Cochran1977}

A regular citation of \citet{Cochran1977}.

\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation of `bibentry` can be found in bibentry.dtx (to be found at CTAN), just `latex` that file.

Comment: I'm afraid that `bibentry` requires the `.bbl` file formatted as expected by `natbib`.

Comment: Imho biblatex works fine with polyglossia.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, will give `biblatex` another chance.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right `biblatex` works with `polyglossia`, but unfortunately `biblatex-apa` does not.

Comment: biblatex-apa works too. You only need the correct language name (polyglossia needs e.g. german instead of ngerman.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, indeed. Works with `german`, `french`, except does not work with `english`. I gues it is because it is `english` for `polyglossia`, but it is `american` or `british` for `biblatex-apa`. Renamed and modified accordingly `british-apa.lbx` to `english-apa.lbx` and it works finally. I do not feel safe with `biblatex-apa` right now.

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors." **Incorrect.** I am having this same problem. Did you ever find a solution using apacite and bibentry?

Comment: Ah, the solution for me was upgrading apacite, and making sure all of my bib entries were not missing any required fields. See [this blog](http://linguisticsblog.com/2013/01/27/inline-apa-bibliography-entry-in-latex/)

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for posting your solution! My solution was to use `apacite` with `bibunits` according to this blog post: http://myowelt.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-make-list-of-own-publications-in.html